# How do data nodes store data in ECK

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, elastic-stack

I'm new to ECK and I'm struggling to find information on how data nodes store data within ECK. My kube cluster has multiple ECK clusters in different namespaces. I use a node selector along with a taint to schedule the nodes where I want them to go.

```
 - name: data
    count: {{ .Values.dataNodeCount }}
    config:
      node.roles: ["data", "ingest", "ml", "transform"]
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: {{ .Values.volumeSize }}
        storageClassName: standard
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          elasticcluster: 'true'
        tolerations:
        - key: "elasticapp"
          operator: "Equal"
          value: "some-app"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
```

This should almost always guarantee that one pod gets scheduled to a node with a taint equal to some-app. But how is data replicated within the data nodes? If I have 3 data nodes is ECK data shared between the 3 nodes? Does each node hold a copy of all of the ECK database and in the event that a node crashes, no data is lost? How often is data replicated between these? Is this something that's controlled within ECK?
I've been poking through documentation and nothing I've been able to locate has been able to give me a clear answer. Ideally I'd like each data node to hold a 1x1 copy of what all the other nodes have so in the even that the pod goes down or one node's data gets corrupted the other node can take over rapidly.